# o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector : Error in I/O with localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

My application consumes messages from a  Kafka server running  on one  machine and then forwards them to another remote Kafka running on some other instance. After I deploy my app to Cloud Foundry and send a message to the first Kafka server, the application works as expected. The message gets consumed and forwards it to the remote Kafka.

However after that I get a infinite loop of the exception below in Cloud Foundry(and on my local machine as well at a slower pace):

StackTrace:

```
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT 2016-06-03 18:20:34.900 WARN 29 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector : Error in I/O with localhost/127.0.0.1
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65-]
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_65-]
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar!/:na]
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar!/:na]
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:238) ~[kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar!/:na]
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.2.jar!/:na]
Fri Jun 03 2016 12:20:34 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) [App/0] OUT at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65-]
```

My application yaml file is like this

Application YML :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        activationMsgQueue:
          binder: kafka1
          destination: test
          contentType: application/json
          consumer:
            resetOffsets: true
            startOffset: latest
        input:
          binder: kafka2
          content-type: application/x-java-object;type=com.comcast.activation.message.vo.ActivationDataInfo
          destination: test
          group: prac  
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              kafka:
                host: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net
        kafka2:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              kafka:
                host: caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
      default-binder: kafka2                    
      kafka:
        binder:
          zk-nodes: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net, caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
```

I have observed that if I include the config below, the error disappears, but now I have a infinite loop of messages getting consumed and sent.

SNIPPET:

```
kafka:
        binder:
           brokers: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net, caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
          zk-nodes: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net, caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
```

What do I need to do to stop this infinite loop?

Hi Marius, Thank you for responding to the SOS call. I have an enhancement to the above problem. The flow is now to consume from a1p(topic:test), and forward to a3p(topic : test) if message is valid else send the erroneous message to a1p(topic:errorMsgQueue). I have the below application. yml file

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        errorMsgQueue:
          binder: kafka1
          destination: errorMsgQueue
          contentType: application/json
        input:
          binder: kafka2
          content-type: application/x-java-object;type=com.comcast.activation.message.vo.ActivationDataInfo
          destination: test
          group: prac
        activationMsgQueue:
          binder: kafka3
          destination: test
          contentType: application/json
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream: 
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net
                      zk-nodes: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net
        kafka2:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
             cloud:
               stream: 
                 kafka:
                   binder:
                     brokers: caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
                     zk-nodes: caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
        kafka3:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
             cloud:
               stream: 
                 kafka:
                   binder:
                     brokers: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net
                     zk-nodes: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net
      default-binder: kafka2

I am still getting an infinite loop. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spring.kafka.host` is not a valid configuration option for Spring Cloud Stream. http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_kafka_binder_properties are the only properties that the binder supports.

Also, it seems like your application is mixing the configurations for the two clusters. (I assume they are separate clusters?)

It should rather be something like this:

`spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        activationMsgQueue:
          binder: kafka1
          destination: test
          contentType: application/json
          consumer:
            resetOffsets: true
            startOffset: latest
        input:
          binder: kafka2
          content-type: application/x-java-object;type=com.comcast.activation.message.vo.ActivationDataInfo
          destination: test
          group: prac

      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net
                      zk-nodes: caapmsg-as-a1p.sys.comcast.net 
        kafka2:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
                      zk-nodes: caapmsg-as-a3p.sys.comcast.net
      default-binder: kafka2`

See this example https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multibinder-differentsystems/src/main/resources/application.yml for details.

I would suspect that the infinite loop is somehow caused by sending and receiving messages to the same topic.

Comment: Hi Marius, Thank you for responding to the SOS call. I have an enhancement to the above problem. Now i have two topics "test" and "errorMsgQueue" to produce to(for erroroneous messages) on a3p and a1p respectively and "test" on a1p  to consume from. I have the below application. yml file

Comment: PLease see the question. I have added the details at the end of the question. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: A couple of things: you don't need a binder per queue - so having the two queues that go to the same cluster share a binder is perfectly fine.

Comment: Secondly, I tried to reproduce your example with our sample app (without introducing the third queue, but I don't think that is relevant), but I saw everything working correctly. My suspicion is that this is a problem with your broker setup and that your two brokers are actually part of the same cluster.  That would mean that the input and output talk to the same topic - which explains the infinite loop - once you write a message on output, it is read by the input and so on. One way to check for that is to write on a different topic and see if you get a separate topic created.

Comment: Once again you are bang on target Marius. The server.properties of a3p was having advertised.host.name = a1p .Things working fine now. thank you for your help.

Comment: Great, glad to be able to help - thanks for using Spring Cloud Stream!